# How to create a network were central nodes represent shared objects?

Tags: python, networkx

I want to create a network with two types of nodes : owners and shared objects.
Here is a toy example, assume that 3 children : Tom, Sam and Mary share 3 pies.

| Name | Pie | Share |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Chocolate | 0.5 |
| Tom | Apple | 0.1 |
| Tom | Pear | 0.4 |
| Sam | Chocolate | 0.3 |
| Sam | Apple | 0.8 |
| Sam | Pear | 0.4 |
| Mary | Chocolate | 0.2 |
| Mary | Apple | 0.1 |
| Mary | Pear | 0.2 |

I would like to use the Network X library in Python to create the desired output :
[image]

Where the size of the edges are weighted by the share of pie each of the child owns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a bipartite network, and you can create that just like a regular network.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_node('Tom')
G.add_node('Sam')
G.add_node('Mary')

G.add_node('Chocolate')
G.add_node('Apple')
G.add_node('Pear')

G.add_edge('Tom','Chocolate',weight=0.5)
G.add_edge('Tom','Apple',weight=0.1)
...
```

You drew directional links, so I used a `DiGraph`, but if you don't care about the direction, then you can just use a regular `Graph`. The fact that it's bipartite just means you can break the full network into two sets of nodes which don't share any edges.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer, is there a way to automate adding nodes and edges by just saying G.add_node(pd["Name"] G.add_node(pd["Pie"]) and G.add_edge(pd["Name"],pd["Pie"],weight=pd["share"]) ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You'd like to loop over some data structure that contains the relevant information?

Comment: Yes, assume that my dataset contains 100 different names and 20 pies it would be a bit tedious to do it manually

Comment: What is the structure of the data?

Comment: A panda dataframe

Comment: you can look at the nx.from_pandas_edgelist() function: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html